# Exclusive access to read a message from Websphere MQ 7, proccess it then delete it

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a queue form which i'd like to be able to retrieve message. I then need to process them somehow (not in the scope) and then remove them from the queue.

I tried to create 2 queues, one that browse the message and one to delete the message after it has been processed.

```
    MQQueue browseQueue = qMgr.AccessQueue(QUEUE_NAME, MQC.MQOO_BROWSE);
    MQGetMessageOptions browseOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions()
    {
        Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT,
        WaitInterval = MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED
    };

    MQQueue acknowledgeQueue = qMgr.AccessQueue(QUEUE_NAME, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF);
    MQGetMessageOptions acknowledgeOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions()
    {
        Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQMO_MATCH_MSG_ID,
        WaitInterval = MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED
    };

    while (keepRunning.WaitOne(0))
    {
        MQMessage browseMessage = new MQMessage();

        try
        {
            browseQueue.Get(browseMessage, browseOptions);
        }
        catch (MQException mqexe)
        {
            throw;
        }

        if (browseMessage.MessageType != ShutDown.TYPE)
        {
            object o = browseMessage.ReadObject();
            Console.WriteLine("The message is: {0}", o);
        }

        browseMessage.ClearMessage();

        MQMessage acknowledgeMessage = new MQMessage()
        {
            MessageId = browseMessage.MessageId
        };
        acknowledgeQueue.Get(acknowledgeMessage, acknowledgeOptions);
    }
```

But I need to make sure no other process can access the same message. Since, I relied on using 2 queues, I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yuk.  You do not understand MQ.  As Attila said, you need to use MQ SyncPoint and if you are happy with the message then commit it, otherwise back it out.  Also, do NOT hard-code queue manager or queue names in your program, you should be reading them from a property file.

Here is how the code should look:

```
MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName);
MQQueue queue = qMgr.AccessQueue(qName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;
gmo.WaitInterval = MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED;
MQMessage receiveMsg;

while (keepRunning.WaitOne(0))
{
   receiveMsg = new MQMessage();

   try
   {
      queue.Get(receiveMsg, gmo);
      if (receiveMsg.MessageType != ShutDown.TYPE)
      {
          object o = receiveMsg.ReadObject();
          Console.WriteLine("The message is: {0}", o);
      }

      qMgr.Commit();
   }
   catch (MQException mqexe)
   {
      qMgr.Backout();
      throw mqexe;
   }
}
```

Comment: Would this prevent another thread to access the same message after the message has been retrieved `queue.Get(receiveMsg, gmo);` but before the manager has commited?

Comment: Yes, after the message is got, it is not available for other threads, until it is backed out (supposing it is ever backed out).

Answer (score 2):

You can handle messages transactionally when using MQ.
So your requirement should be met by using 1 input queue and reading messages from that queue under syncpoint.

So your application should first get the message under syncpoint (it is a get message option), do the processing, and if that succeeds it can commit the MQ transaction, else it can roll it back, thus putting the message back to the queue unchanged, or even better move the message to the backout queue and use the transactionality to safeguard against unexpected errors in your application. 
This method automatically meets your requirement that 1 message should not be available for parallel reads.

Anyway your proposed method doesn't really make sense, 1 message is put to 1 queue, how would you get it to both of your proposed input queues, and even after doing that, getting a message from a queue doesn't affect messages or browse cursors on a different queue.